# Returning the content of multiple files in node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, fs

Im using the `fs` module of node.js to read all the files of a directory and return their content, but the array i use to store the content is always empty.

server-side:

```
app.get('/getCars', function(req, res){
   var path = __dirname + '/Cars/';
   var cars = [];

   fs.readdir(path, function (err, data) {
       if (err) throw err;

        data.forEach(function(fileName){
            fs.readFile(path + fileName, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;

                files.push(data);
            });
        });
    });
    res.send(files);  
    console.log('complete'); 
});
```

ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/getCars',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   contentType: 'application/json'
}).done(function( response ) {
      console.log(response);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are doing it wrong, you are sending results without knowing that fs.readFile is running async on each file, that means file is not read niether contents are pushed to array and array is already sent to client

Comment: I don't know who down-voted this question, If this questions is invalid one should comment while down-voting. All questions are not dumb, If some one is new to async style of paradigm he/she will do such coding.

Comment: I though that my problem was that i was using async methods but i tried using their sync counterparts (`readdirSync`,`readFileSync`) and still didn't get the expected result.

Comment: don't do sync coding, make most of async, see the simulated version here it works very well, https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/files/read_dir_files.js

Comment: It really works well, how can i learn more about the async functions on node.js?. Btw thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read content of all files inside a directory and send results to client, as:

choice 1 using `npm install async`

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('async');

var dirPath = 'path_to_directory/'; //provice here your path to dir

fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, filesPath) {
    if (err) throw err;
    filesPath = filesPath.map(function(filePath){ //generating paths to file
        return dirPath + filePath;
    });
    async.map(filesPath, function(filePath, cb){ //reading files or dir
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', cb);
    }, function(err, results) {
        console.log(results); //this is state when all files are completely read
        res.send(results); //sending all data to client
    });
});
```

choice 2 using `npm install read-multiple-files`

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    readMultipleFiles = require('read-multiple-files');

fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, filesPath) {
    if (err) throw err;
    filesPath = filesPath.map(function (filePath) {
        return dirPath + filePath;
    });
    readMultipleFiles(filesPath, 'utf8', function (err, results) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log(results); //all files read content here
    });
});
```

For complete working solution get this [Github Repo](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/files/read_dir_files.js) and run `read_dir_files.js`

Happy Helping!

Comment: After `npm install async` ;)

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks!. I just have one doubt, what is the function of the `cb` parameter on the `async.map()` function?

Comment: cb is callback that is supposed to be called when some-work is done, like file read is complete in this case, for that you will have to understand asynchronous nature :)

Comment: I'll deepen more into the asynchronous nature. Thanks for all your help!