# node js read files line by line

Tags: node.js, file, directory, readline

I am quite new with Node.js.

There is a folder on my computer where I have several textfiles (`.fw4` format). I could find all the text files with the `node-dir` module.

Furthermore I need to get some content of each file from specified columns. Actually this algorithm works fine, using the `readline` module.

I keep my files name in an array.
Something like this: `[ '000037592.fw4', '000037593.fw4', '000037594.fw4' ]`

What do I need actually? I would like that this whole system would work synchronously and when I get the first file content (`000037592.fw4`) it would log something like end of file. And it continues reading the other files from the array.

So far, it has not worked how I wanted.

Thank you so much in advance. I would appreciate any suggestion on how to get a solution for my problem.

Comment: similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823727/returning-the-content-of-multiple-files-in-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like:

```
var fileArray = [ '000037592.fw4', '000037593.fw4', '000037594.fw4' ];
var i = 0;
readNextFile();

function readNextFile(){
    fs.readFile(fileArray[i++], function(result){
        handleResult(result);

        if(i < fileArray.length){
            readNextFile();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How Could I write the content of each file to the console? It is necessary because later I need to the send the files to the server...I want something like if it finished reading the first file write to the console: "End of reading first file"..and so on..

Comment: @NagyGergő I'm glad I've managed to help you. You have to mark my answer as the accepted answer first (click the V on the left), as well as to vote up (click the up arrow on the left). For any other problem you have, please open a new question. Notice that by accepting an answer you will get reputation points that will give you some privileges in this site. You write to console by the command "console.log()".